# Download file with rn-fetch-blob with POST

Tags: android, react-native

I'm use rn-fetch-blob, how can I download the file where I need to pass some parameters in the body of the request with POST? I've tried this:

```
RNFetchBlob
            .config({
                // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
                // this is much more performant.
                fileCache: true,
                path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir + '/video.mp4'
            })
            .fetch('POST', `${SERVER}/get_video`, {
                unique_key: TerminalID(),
                id_midia: '2'
            })
            .then((res) => {
                // the temp file path
                Alert.alert('Caminho', 'The file saved to ' + res.path())
                this.setState({ download: true, downloadActionFinished: true })
            })
```

But the API don't receive the data that I pass on body of request

Comment: `but don't works` is not an error description.

Comment: The API don't receive the data that I pass on body of request

Answer (score 0):

You basically didn't attach a body to your request:

```
fetch(method, url, headers, body)
```

See here: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/Fetch-API

Answer (score -1):

```
var tempParam = [{name: 'image',filename: 'image.jpg',data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(uri}]
```

`name` is the key. `filename` is required if you send a file to API. The method to wrap data of file can be found at fetch API (if im not wrong)